# Using canvas in Netbeans GUI builder

Tags: java

I'm trying to use canvas in java. I'm using netbeans GUI builder to add several canvases to the window but I'm not sure how to for example draw the line or rectangle on them. I read several manuals how to do that but I'm still beginner in Java and I didn't quite understand what am I supposed to do. The constructor of the class looks like this:

```
public Classname() {
        initComponents();
  canvas1.setBackground(Color.red); // That works.
// Now I want to (for example) draw a line on the canvas1 (or some other canvas)
    }
```

Could somebody please explain me what code should I write and where to put it? Thanks in advance. (Sorry for my english.)

Comment: Assuming your using "java.awt.Canavs", then I'd recommend not to. Also, for custom painting, you won't be able to use the form editor directly. You're going to have to create your own custom component and paint on to it. You should then be able to add this component to another form

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your mean `java.awt.Canvas`, I'd recommend that you shouldn't be using it.  Two main reasons, one, it's a heavy weight component, which introduces a list of issues when mixed with Swing/lightweight components and two, it's not double buffered, which just adds additional overheads you're going to have to deal with.

The preferred means by which to perform custom painting is to generally create a new class that extends from `JPanel` and the override it's `paintComponent` method for example

```
public class PaintPane extends JPanel {

    public PaintPane () {
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.drawLine(0, getHeight() / 2, getWidth(), getHeight() / 2);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

}
```

This will draw a simple line across the middle of the panel.

You can then drag the class from the "Projects" tab into the form editor (and onto an existing form container), like you would with components from the palette

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details

**Updated with example based on comments**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class DrawExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DrawExample();
    }

    private DrawPane drawPane;

    public DrawExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                drawPane = new DrawPane();
                JButton addRect = new JButton("Add Rectangle");
                addRect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        int width = drawPane.getWidth() - 1;
                        int height = drawPane.getHeight() - 1;

                        int x = (int)(Math.random() * (width - 5));
                        int y = (int)(Math.random() * (height - 5));

                        width -= x;
                        height -= y;
                        int rectWidth = (int)(Math.random() * width);
                        int rectHeight = (int)(Math.random() * height / 2);

                        drawPane.addRect(x, y, rectWidth, rectHeight);
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(drawPane);
                frame.add(addRect, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class DrawPane extends JPanel {

        private List<Shape> shapes;

        public DrawPane() {
            shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>(25);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            for (Shape shape : shapes) {
                g2d.draw(shape);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        public void addRect(int x, int y, int width, int height) {

            shapes.add(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
            repaint();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Tha didn't really answer my question. I need to be able to repaint the paintpane/canvas depending on which button user presses etc... and I still don't know ho to do that.

Comment: I see nothing about responding to user interaction via buttons in your original question...

Comment: I probably didn't explain it correctly. But essentially I don't need just draw on the canvas/paintpane once but I need to be able to change it repeatedly from the main application class depending on user's actions (buttonclick was just example).

Comment: E.g. I'd like to do something like canvas1.getGraphics().drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100); . But that doesn't work.

Comment: This is not how painting works in Swing, which suggests that you're not reading the linked tutorials